# Glassfish4 Jersey 2.22. CDI1x ClassCastException

Tags: glassfish, jersey-2.0

Please consider the following issue.
While trying to deploy my simple REST application on GlassFish 4.1.1 (Java EE 7 Full Platform) I get the error specified below . My application comprises glassfish-web.xml for configuring class loading delegation so as application uses it's own jersey bundle which is version 2.22

The error I get is the following:

[2016-03-28T13:30:58.035-0400] [glassfish 4.1] [SEVERE] [] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=43 _ThreadName=admin-listener(3)] [timeMillis: 1459186258035] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  WebModule[/device-backend]Servlet /device-backend threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi1x.transaction.internal.TransactionalExceptionInterceptorProvider to org.glassfish.jersey.server.spi.ComponentProvider
        at java.lang.Class.cast(Class.java:3186)

Jersey dependency from pom are as follows:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>2.22</version>
</dependency>  
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <!-- if your container implements Servlet API older than 3.0, use "jersey-container-servlet-core" --> 
    <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.22</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.bundles</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxrs-ri</artifactId>
    <version>2.22</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
    <version>1.19</version>
</dependency>
```

Without glassfish-web.xml everything deploys fine.